# Get the length of an array using document.getElementsbyName()

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an array like this.

```
 var i;
 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
     $('<input/>').attr('type','text')
                 .attr('name','TxtBx_[]')
                 .attr('id','TxtBx_' + i)
                 .attr("readonly","readonly")
                 .attr('value',i)
                 .addClass('txtbx')
                 .appendTo($div);
    }
```

And I prints the 10 input boxes well.

Later I need to get the number of text boxes I have created. So I'm using

```
var myarr=document.getElementsByName('TxtBx_');
var numberofElements=myarr.length;
```

but when I put an alert to check the value of numberofElements it gives me always 0. The length of the array must be 10. Could someone please let me know the mistake I have made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements' names are `TextBx[]`, not `TxtBx_`.

```
var myarr=document.getElementsByName('TextBx[]');
var numberofElements=myarr.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Element names are `TextBx[]` and `TxtBx_` is a class name

```
var myarr=document.getElementsByName('TextBx[]');
var numberofElements=myarr.length;
```

Read [getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) documentation for more information

Answer (score 1):

Because no element has name `TxtBx_` . It's `TextBx[]` actually.

Since you are alrady using jQuery, you can find by class like below,

`$('.txtbx')`.length

Few other things, I would like to add here.

`attr` accepts a object too. So, you can pass all inputs at once. Also, you can pass attributes as second arguement while dynamically creating `input`. Also, according to jQuery docs, you should specify `type` in `input` type while dynamically creating them or it won't work in some IE.

So, try something like this,

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
     $('<input type="text"/>',{
                 'name': 'TxtBx_[]',
                 'id': 'TxtBx_' + i,
                 'readonly':'readonly'
                 'value': i,
                 'class': 'txtbx'
     }).appendTo($div);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numberofElements = document.getElementsByName("TextBx[]").length;
```

Name of textbox is `'name','TxtBx_[]'` getting by `TxtBx_`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$("input.txtbx").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the class to get them:

```
var numberofElements = $('.txtbx').length;
```